# Dynamically change stylesheet onclick anywhere on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if there's a way to keep changing the stylesheet (so a series of five or so) of the whole page every time the user clicks anywhere at all.

Maybe using the `$(document).click` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your main `<link>` tag an id  and create array of the href url's you want.

```
<link data-style_index="0" id="main-style" href="main.css" rel=.... >
```

jQuery:

```
var styles =['url1.css','url2.css','url3.css'...];

$(document).click(function(){
   var $link =$('#main-style'),
       // get index stored on element data and increment
       nextIndex = $link.data('style_index') + 1;
   //revert to first if at last one already
   if( nextIndex === styles.length){
      nextIndex = 0;
    }
    // change the href and store new index value in tag data
    $link.attr('href', styles[nextIndex]).data('style_index', nextIndex);  

});
```

Using the element itself to store the current index for the styles array in html5 `data-` attribute

Comment: It's actually not totally unusual concept...will see it on "theme switchers" . Feel free to accept answer if it helped

Comment: just to mention that you can define `data` attribute anyway, not only in html5. you can define your own attribute in HTML4 with yourown name. html5 gives a diferent storage capabilities as storing different types of data, but each attribute can stoare a string or number. keep in mind that using your own attribute different than `data` will work, but during an HTML validity check will give you a warning.

Answer (score 0):

selects all tags inside body and on click change color property to #ccc:

```
$('*','body').click(function() { $(this).css('color', '#cccccc'); });
```

Comment: Hi @Reflective, thanks for the reply, I'm not sure this is quite what I'm looking for. I’m looking to continually change the css files with every click of the body. Where on this example would I put that it needs to link to a stylesheet or a href or rel?

again, thanks for the help.
-D

Comment: now i see, you need to changes css files, not rules, misunderstanding.